# restore application in old state after automatic shutdown of application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

how to save the page state in WPF on automatic shutdown of application,so that when application is run again,same page in same old condition is displayed?

Comment: restore application state not page state

Comment: You are going to need to serialize the state and load it when your application starts.  If you are using MVVM, you would serialize the VM on exit, then deserialize on startup.

Comment: Guo..can u please post a small example on this

Comment: thanks,but there is error in that code and also in that code,they are saving state of file Test.Xaml but if some other page was opened and the application shutdowns,then how to restore that some other page on running the application again

Comment: It actually doesn't matter what example I pull - the general idea is the same.  Serialize model or viewmodel OnExit, deserialize OnStart.   Everything is the same as a normal MVVM app except you pass the deserialized model to the VM.  How you serialize is up to you (xml,json, binary, database, etc).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(v=vs.110).aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c6100f34-64e0-4a5e-a25a-83a8566fc27d/mvvm-serialization-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guo said, use serialization. Example:

```
using using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
[Serializable]
class Example
{
    private int i;
    private void Save(string fileToSave)
    {
        using(Stream writer = File.OpenWrite(fileToSave))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
    }
    private void Load(string loadFromFile)
    {
        using (Stream reader = File.OpenRead(loadFromFile))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            Example temp = (Example)bf.Deserialize(reader);
            //and here you can restore your class from loadFromFile
            this.i = temp.i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cherkasov Kirill-filetoSave is the name of the Xaml file of which the serialization is to be done?

Comment: No, it is name of the file, where you will save your class.